# ElasticSearch : Is it possible to loop with mustache in a ElasticSearchTemplate

Tags: loops, elasticsearch, templates, mustache

In an ElasticSearch Template , I would like to to that :

```
  "aggs": {
        "att_characteristic": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              {{#agg-att}}
              "{{code}}" : {"term": { "characteristic.code": "{{code}}"}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
              {{/agg-att}}
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_by_value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "characteristic.value",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "top_reverse_nested": {
                  "reverse_nested": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
   "reason" : "Improperly closed variable in query-template:1 @[query-template:1]"
```

It bugs at :

```
{{#agg-att}}
  "{{code}}" : {"term": { "characteristic.code": "{{code}}"}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
{{/agg-att}}
```

Can we loop in an ElasticSearch Template with Mustache language as in another language?

PS : It is called with

```
GET index-name-dev/_search/template
{
  "id": "search-template-test",
  "params": {
    "agg-att":[{"code":"Color"},
               {"code":"Shape"},
               {"code":"Size"}]
  }
}
```

Thanks !

UPDATE : Here below is a full example

The mapping is the following :

```
PUT tly-idx_test1
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fieldA": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "fieldArrayA": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
     "fieldArrayB": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "color": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "text": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
                }
              }
          },
          "shape": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
                }
              }
            },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
                }
              }
            },
          "obligatoire": {
            "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
     },
      "fieldB": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldC": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldD": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldE": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here below is some data to put in the test index

```
POST tly-idx_test1/_doc
{
  "fieldA": "M",
  "fieldB": "SHOWER PACK",
  "fieldC": "false",
  "fieldD": "01",
  "fieldE": "true",
  "fieldArrayA": [
    "val1",
    "val2",
    "val3"
  ],
   "fieldArrayB": [
    {"color":"red","size":"10cm","shape":"square","obligatoire":true,"value":"15"},
    {"color":"blue","size":"100cm","shape":"circle","obligatoire":true ,"value":"25"},
    {"color":"green","size":"50cm","shape":"rectangle","obligatoire":true ,"value":"35"},
    {"color":"yellow","size":"22cm","shape":"triangle","obligatoire":true ,"value":"45"}
    
  ]
}
```

Here below is the template

```
GET tly-idx_test1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg-attributs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "fieldArrayB"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "att_obligatoire": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              {{#agg-att}}
              "{{code}}" : {"term": { "fieldArrayB.color": "{{code}}"}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
              {{/agg-att}}
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_by_value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "fieldArrayB.value",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "top_reverse_nested": {
                  "reverse_nested": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compressed :

```
PUT _scripts/tly-template-test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": "{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"aggregations\":{\"agg-attributs\":{\"nested\":{\"path\":\"fieldArrayB\"},\"aggs\":{\"att_obligatoire\":{\"filters\":{\"filters\":{{{#agg-att}}\"{{code}}\":{\"term\":{\"fieldArrayB.color\":\"{{code}}\"}}{{^last}},{{/last}}{{/agg-att}}}},\"aggs\":{\"agg_by_value\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"fieldArrayB.value\",\"size\":10000},\"aggs\":{\"top_reverse_nested\":{\"reverse_nested\":{}}}}}}}}}}"
  }
}
```

Finally, here below is the template calling :

```
GET tly-idx_test1/_search/template
{
  "id": "tly-template-test",
  "params": {
    "agg-att": [{"code": "color"},
                {"code": "shape"},
                {"code": "size","last": true}
    ]
  }
}
```

I got the same error

```
"reason" : "Improperly closed variable in query-template:1 @[query-template:1]"
```

Why does the loop does not work?

Comment: Can you show how you invoke the template with the exact parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just forget to specify `last` in the last element

```
GET index-name-dev/_search/template
{
  "id": "search-template-test",
  "params": {
    "agg-att": [
      {
        "code": "Color"
      },
      {
        "code": "Shape"
      },
      {
        "code": "Size",
        "last": true            <---- add this
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem is in your compressed version some curly braces are too close to one another and that goes in the way of some [mustache syntax rules](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) (two `{{` and three `{{{` don't mean the same thing)

You need to add one space here

```
...{\"filters\":{ {{#agg-att}}\"{{code}}\":{\"term\":{\"fieldArrayB.color\":\"{{code}}\"}}...
                 ^
                 |
             add space
```

and another here

```
...{{^last}},{{/last}}{{/agg-att}} }},...
                                  ^
                                  |
                              add space
```

Which is why it's always better and more legible to use a fully formatted template, like the one below:

```
POST _scripts/tly-template-test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """
  {
    "query":{
      "match_all":{}
    },
    "aggregations":{
      "agg-attributs":{
        "nested":{
          "path":"fieldArrayB"
        },
        "aggs":{
          "att_obligatoire":{
            "filters":{
              "filters":{
                {{#agg-att}}
                  "{{code}}":{
                    "term":{
                      "fieldArrayB.color":"{{code}}"
                    }
                  }{{^last}},{{/last}}
                {{/agg-att}}
              }
            },
            "aggs":{
              "agg_by_value":{
                "terms":{
                  "field": "fieldArrayB.value",
                  "size":10000
                },
                "aggs":{
                  "top_reverse_nested":{
                    "reverse_nested":{}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it still does not work

Comment: Weird, because I was able to install your template as is and it worked out. Maybe you're not showing the full template, do you mind adding it completely?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot post the whole template because  it is too big. But If I change {{#agg-att}}
  "{{code}}" : {"term": { "characteristic.code": "{{code}}"}}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
{{/agg-att}} By  "Color" : {"term": { "characteristic.code": "Color"}}, the template works....I assume this is the mustchache looping which does not work ... Or the params settings are wrong in my code. I am still checking ...

Comment: Again just the aggs part works fine as it is for me, provided I add the `last:true` to the last element... so it must be something wrong with your query part

Comment: I updated the post with a full example. I still got the error...I am still looking for a solution. If you check anything wrong let me know :) Thanks (I did it fast, I hope I did not let some mistakes)

Comment: I figured out the problem, see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you ! Yes, It solved the problem. I used the compress template because of the kibana console.  With mustache variable, I have syntax error in the console. Thanks !

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! You can do it in Kibana by using the three ticks notation `"""`